# Ubuntu - php chmod() not changing the file permissions after creation by copy

Tags: php, apache

I have the following code running on ubuntu,apache,php

```
if (!file_exists(THIS_DIR."DEFINE.php")) {
    copy(THIS_DIR."DEFINE.default.php",THIS_DIR."DEFINE.php");
    chmod(THIS_DIR."DEFINE.php",777);
}
```

after this run this code, I check the file in terminal:

```
$ ls -l DEFINE*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 353 2015-11-25 13:28 DEFINE.default.php
-r----x--t 1 www-data www-data 353 2016-03-16 12:44 DEFINE.php
```

As u can see the file is created, own by the apache process, but chmod didn't work, and the file cannot be edited by the apache process.

Why is that?

The code works on my win dev env, how can I make it work on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below its worked for me:

> chmod(THIS_DIR."DEFINE.php",0777);

instead

> chmod(THIS_DIR."DEFINE.php",777);